# Non-overflowing avg calculation with integer arithmetic

Tags: java, integer, statistics

I have multiple `long` values and I want to calculate their average value using integer arithmetic, without precision loss and using java rounding rules for division, i.e. when `N` is `10` and sum is `+/- 29`, then `29/10 == 2` and `-29/10 == -2`, not `-3`.

The code should handle situations when the sum of all elements overflows the type.

The resulting type should be the same as the elements' type, not `double`.

It is ok to return bad result if `N` exceeds the maximum supported value for the element type

The code should not use a bigger type to store the sum, because there can be no bigger type, when elements are of type `long` in java or `intmax_t` in c++. Using `double` can lead to precision loss; arbitrary precision integers like `BigInteger` are too slow for this task.

I found a solution that best suits me: [How can I compute the average of a large array of integers without running into overflow?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-compute-the-average-of-a-large-array-of-integers-without-running-into-overflow). In short: they divide each element before summing and therefore avoid the overflow.

As the first replier said, I adapted it for negative values. There was a divisor overflow check: `y >= N - b`, I replaced it with the type overflow check: when the sign of the remainder sum changes, I increment or decrement the current avg. For some reason, it works even when the sign changes not because of an overflow.

There's also [Precise and safe calculation method for the average of large integer arrays](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/807195/Precise-and-safe-calculation-method-for-the-averag), but I found it later and I didn't have time to check. On first glance, they don't check the `cumulated_remainder` overflow in case of many elements.

I chose to use 8-bit integers for the test implementation, because they're easier to count mentally. Also, it is possible to check all value combinations in short arrays in reasonable time.

In some places I use the addition assignment operator `+=` instead of assignment to avoid unnecessary casts.

`avg_slow()` is using `BigInteger` to produce the expected results for comparison.

```
static byte avg(final byte[] vals) {
    final int n = vals.length;
    byte avg = 0, remsum = 0, remrem = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        final byte val = vals[i];
        avg += val / n;
        final byte oldremsum = remsum;
        byte rem = 0;
        rem += val % n;
        remsum += rem;

        if (oldremsum < 0) {
            if (remsum >= 0 && rem < 0) {
                avg--;
                remsum += n;
            }
        } else if (oldremsum > 0 && remsum < 0 && rem > 0) {
            avg++;
            remsum -= n;
        }
    }
    avg += remsum / n;
    remrem += remsum % n;
    if (avg < 0 && remrem > 0) {
        avg++;
    } else if (avg > 0 && remrem < 0) {
        avg--;
    }
    return avg;
}

static void calcAndCompare(final byte[] vals) {
    final byte avgex = avg_slow(vals);
    final byte avgact = avg(vals);
    if (avgact != avgex) {
        System.out.println("ex:" + avgex + " act:" + avgact + " " + Arrays.toString(vals));
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

static void test129() {
    final byte[] vals = new byte[129];
    Arrays.fill(vals, (byte) -128);
    calcAndCompare(vals);
}

static void test100() {
    final byte[] vals = new byte[120];
    vals[0] = -1;
    vals[1] = 100;
    calcAndCompare(vals);
}

static void testMaxN() {
    byte b = 1;
    while ((b <<= 1) > 0);
    b--;
    final byte[] vals = new byte[(int)(b > Short.MAX_VALUE ? Short.MAX_VALUE : b)];

    Arrays.fill(vals, b);
    calcAndCompare(vals);

    b++;

    Arrays.fill(vals, b);
    calcAndCompare(vals);
}

static void test67() {

    byte b = 1;
    while ((b <<= 1) > 0);
    b--;

    final byte[] vals = new byte[67];

    Arrays.fill(vals, (byte) -110);
    calcAndCompare(vals);

    Arrays.fill(vals, (byte) 110);
    calcAndCompare(vals);

    double d = b;
    d++;
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        vals[i] = (byte) ((Math.random() * 2 * d) - d);
    }
    calcAndCompare(vals);
}

static void testAllCombinations(final int depth, final byte... vals) {
    if (depth == vals.length) {
        calcAndCompare(vals);
        return;
    }
    for (byte b1 = Byte.MIN_VALUE;; b1++) {
        vals[depth] = b1;
        testAllCombinations(depth + 1, vals);
        if (b1 == Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    test100();
    testMaxN();
    test129();

    test67();

    testAllCombinations(0, new byte[2]);
    testAllCombinations(0, new byte[3]);
}

static byte avg_slow(final byte[] vals) {
    if (false) {
        return avg(vals);
    }
    final int n = vals.length;
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        final byte val = vals[i];
        sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(val));
    }
    byte res = 0;
    res += sum.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(n)).longValue();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Indeed. If n > 128 then val / n == 0 and val % n == n, therefore remsum += val % n can overflow.

Comment: @MartinR fixed by `remsum >= 0`

Comment: Unless I made an error, it still fails for a 1000-element array filled with 127.

Comment: I wonder if the pair of `avg` and `remsum` can unambiguously describe the avg in case of very big `N`

Comment: Those problems arise because you chose a very small data type, so that adding two remainders (which are in the range -N+1...N-1) might result in an overflow. I *assume* that your algorithm works correctly if N is less that half of the maximal integer value. For 32-bit int or 64-bit long that would not be a substantial restriction.

Comment: @MartinR added: `It is ok to return bad result if N exceeds the maximum supported value for the element type`

Comment: Wrong result for 120-element array `-1, 100, 0, ..., 0`

Comment: Looks like we need 3 comparisons to detect an overflow

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 4):

This is Java, not C. You don't have to declare all the variables at the start of the method. There are 20 lines between the declaration of `remrem` and the first use. Keeping variables to the smallest scope possible aids readability.

Also, it's not obligatory to declare variables to be equal to the "default" value. Observe:

> ```
>     byte ... remrem = 0;
>     ...
>     remrem += remsum % n;
> ```

and

> ```
>         byte rem = 0;
>         rem += val % n;
> ```

Both of those could be simplified to a simple initialisation to the desired value and made `final`.

---

Arguably an extension of minimising scope is avoiding unnecessary variables.

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
>         final byte val = vals[i];
> ```

could perfectly well be

```
 for (byte val : vals) {
```

since `i` is not used elsewhere.

---

> ```
>         if (oldremsum < 0) {
>             if (remsum >= 0 && rem < 0) {
>                 avg--;
>                 remsum += n;
>             }
>         } else if (oldremsum > 0 && remsum < 0 && rem > 0) {
>             avg++;
>             remsum -= n;
>         }
> ```

I understand (for the most part) why this is written as it is, but the asymmetry slowed me down slightly. (The bit I still don't understand is why one half uses `>=` and the other half uses `<`). Would it be preferable to make the test symmetric using basic properties of twos-complement numbers?

```
    if ((oldremsum ^ remsum) < 0 && (oldremsum ^ rem) >= 0) {
        // Sign of remsum has changed when adding a number of the same sign,
        // so there has been overflow.
        if (rem < 0) {
            avg--;
            remsum += n;
        }
        else {
            avg++;
            remsum -= n;
        }
    }
```